# How to get the partial value of a XML Node value

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I'm new to Xpath and This is my XML . I'm trying to the get the attribute value @name in the appl/*__job tag and the value 'TESTQUEUE 'in the node snmp_notify/message and I'm taking one step at a time. As of now I was able to get the child nodes of all _job, but I couldn't get the value in the node /snmp_notifylist/snmp_notify/message. This is the SQL and Could someone help me with identifying where I got stuck.

This is the Sample XML Document stored as DEFINITION in the table TAB_AR.

```
<appl xmlns="http://dto.wa.ca.com/application" name="TEST_NEW_AGENT">
   <version>12.0</version>
   <comment />
   <unix_job name="TEST_JOB">
     <dependencies><relcount>0</relcount></dependencies>
      <snmp_notifylist>
       <snmp_notify>
         <returncode>4</returncode>
           <monitor_states><monitor_state>FAILED</monitor_state></monitor_states>
           <snmpagent />
           <message>TICKET TESTQUEUE TSTMSG</message>
      </snmp_notify>
   </snmp_notifylist>
 </unix_job>
 <link name="HOLD_LINK">
    <dependencies><relcount>0</relcount></dependencies>
    <hold>true</hold>
   <job_ancestor_wait_default_ignore>true</job_ancestor_wait_default_ignore>
 </link>
 <sftp_job name="TEST_SFTP1">
    <dependencies><relcount>0</relcount></dependencies>
    <snmp_notifylist>
         <snmp_notify>
           <returncode>4</returncode>
             <monitor_states>
                 <monitor_state>FAILED</monitor_state>
             </monitor_states>
            <snmpagent />
            <message>TICKET MFG1AWA TSTMSG</message>
            </snmp_notify>
    </snmp_notifylist>
</sftp_job>
</appl>
```

And this is the SQL I wrote,

```
 SELECT  
 SFTP_Job_name = DEFT1.value('(@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
 Server_Address = DEFT1.query('local-name(/*:snmp_notifylist/*:snmp_notify/*:message)')
 from (select CAST([DEFINITION] as XML) as DEFT from TAB_AR)TAB
 CROSS APPLY TAB.DEFT.nodes('/*:appl/*[fn:contains(local-name(),"_job")]') as XMLTAB1(DEFT1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close...

In this line I'm not sure, what you really wanted to get:

```
DEFT1.query('local-name(/*:snmp_notifylist/*:snmp_notify/*:message)')
```

With `local-name()` you can return the name of one specific node. As you are reading from several nodes ending on `_job` it perfectly makes sense to return the name of the element you are reading from.

But you are telling us, that you are trying to read the `<message>` too. Might be, that you are mixing two calls in one line?

I slightly modified your code:

```
SELECT 
  SFTP_Job_name = DEFT1.value('(@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 ,NodeName = DEFT1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
 ,Server_Address = DEFT1.value('(*:snmp_notifylist/*:snmp_notify/*:message)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 from (select CAST([DEFINITION] as XML) as DEFT from TAB_AR)TAB
 CROSS APPLY TAB.DEFT.nodes('/*:appl/*[fn:contains(local-name(.),"_job")]') as XMLTAB1(DEFT1);
```

This returns

```
SFTP_Job_name   NodeName    Server_Address
TEST_SFTP1      sftp_job    TICKET MFG1AWA TSTMSG
TEST_JOB        unix_job    TICKET TESTQUEUE TSTMSG
```

Like Roger Wolf pointed out, it was better to read with a specified namespaces like this:

```
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://dto.wa.ca.com/application')
 SELECT 
  SFTP_Job_name = DEFT1.value('(@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 ,NodeName = DEFT1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
 ,Server_Address = DEFT1.value('(snmp_notifylist/snmp_notify/message)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 from (select CAST([DEFINITION] as XML) as DEFT from TAB_AR)TAB
 CROSS APPLY TAB.DEFT.nodes('/appl/*[fn:contains(local-name(.),"_job")]') as XMLTAB1(DEFT1);
```

The general rule is: *Be as specific as possible!*

### Hint

If you can change this, you should store your XML in a column of type `XML`.
This construction `from (select CAST([DEFINITION] as XML) as DEFT from TAB_AR)TAB` should really not be necessary...

Might be, that your column is `XML` actually and you just did not know how to transfer the code you found somewhere to get the right syntax for the `.nodes()`? In this case just try this:

```
SELECT 
  SFTP_Job_name = DEFT1.value('(@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 ,NodeName = DEFT1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
 ,Server_Address = DEFT1.value('(*:snmp_notifylist/*:snmp_notify/*:message)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 from TAB_AR
 CROSS APPLY TAB_AR.[DEFINITION].nodes('/*:appl/*[fn:contains(local-name(.),"_job")]') as XMLTAB1(DEFT1);
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo !!

Comment: Apologies ..  I just did .. I keep it in mind for next time, Thank you very much !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://dto.wa.ca.com/application')
select j.c.value('./@name', 'sysname') as [JobName],
    m.c.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [MessageText]
from (
    select cast(t.[Definition] as xml) as [Deft] from tab_ar t
) sq
    cross apply sq.Deft.nodes('/appl/*[fn:contains(local-name(),"_job")]') j(c)
        cross apply j.c.nodes('./snmp_notifylist/snmp_notify/message') m(c);
```

After that, splitting the string by spaces and taking the middle part should be relatively trivial.

Comment: Hi Roger, Thanks for your reply. However I need to fetch the attribute 'name' /appl/*_job.

Comment: Voted this up for the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`. Just one hint: It should work a bit faster, to read the `<message>` directly below `j(c)`, no second `CROSS APPLY` needed...

Comment: @Shnugo, if OP needs just this single element - maybe; however, usually it's more than that, and `apply` will be justifiable. Besides, I have noticed many times that relative performance of various XML methods in SQL Server varies considerably with engine version, so I didn't even try to optimise anything.